# Is there any simpler method in pandas to replace null values other than loop in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to replace the null values with the mode of numbers in each group(groupby area).
Is there any simpler method in Pandas to do this?

I've done it through loop method which is not recommended for very large datasets.

```
data = {'area':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc','bcd', 'bcd', 'bcd' , 
'cde','cde', 'cde', 'cde', 'cde'], 'number':[1, 2, 2, np.nan, 3, 3, 
np.nan, 5, 5, 4, np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Hell = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("area")['number'].agg(lambda 
x:x.value_counts().index[0])).reset_index()

import math
for index in range(0,df.shape[0]):   
    if math.isnan(df['number'][index]):
        for i in range(0,Hell.shape[0]):
            if Hell['area'][i] == df['area'][index]:
                df['number'][index] = Hell['number'][i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for replace by matched values by `area`:

```
df['number'] = df['number'].fillna(df['area'].map(Hell.set_index('area')['number']))
print (df)
   area  number
0   abc     1.0
1   abc     2.0
2   abc     2.0
3   abc     2.0
4   bcd     3.0
5   bcd     3.0
6   bcd     3.0
7   cde     5.0
8   cde     5.0
9   cde     4.0
10  cde     5.0
11  cde     5.0
```

Or use your solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for same Series like original filled by aggregate values:

```
s = df.groupby("area")['number'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
#alternative
#s = df.groupby("area")['number'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
df['number'] = df['number'].fillna(s)
print (df)
   area  number
0   abc     1.0
1   abc     2.0
2   abc     2.0
3   abc     2.0
4   bcd     3.0
5   bcd     3.0
6   bcd     3.0
7   cde     5.0
8   cde     5.0
9   cde     4.0
10  cde     5.0
11  cde     5.0
```